# Oracle APEX Interactive grid overflows the region

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a couple of interactive grids on my page and one of them is overflowing the region. I have tried resizing columns but no matter what I do, the grid bounces right back - overflowing the region. It almost seems as if there is a minimum width property set somewhere but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Look at this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4005021 and this http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/06/interactive-grid-column-widths/. I installed the sample interactive grid application here and the reports have the same problem. The first one sugestion works here.

Answer (score 1):

Under Advanced settings for the interactive grid there is a column that says custom attributes. This field allows you to type in CSS that can override the default CSS. My recommendation would be to play with this column with commands such as

```
style="width: 90%;"
```

This would reduce the maximum width the interactive grid will take up (from 100% of screen to 90% of screen).

Additionally when looking at the page you can hit F12 to open a web inspect that could help show more details about the CSS of the grid. If this doesn't help could you provide a screenshot or demo so we can further assist.